# Is there any way that Azure Loadbalancer talks to Virtual Machines which only have private IP address?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-load-balancer

Need to configure a Azure Loadbalancer for VM's in VNet with only private IP's, but without VM's having public IP we cannot map to the loadbalancer. Why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly, you can target VMs with only private IPs and without public IPs to the backend pool of Azure load balancer. If so, you could access the backend VMs via the load balancer public IP address.

For example, you can create a [Standard Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-standard-overview) as the internal or public load balancer. Standard Load Balancer is fully integrated with the scope of a virtual network. It supports the VMs with standard SKU public IP or without public IP in a VNet as the backend resources.

[Quickstart: Create a Standard Load Balancer to load balance VMs using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/quickstart-load-balancer-standard-public-portal)

Comment: basic loadbalancers also support internal (private) VMs to be attached to the loadbalancer: you'd need the VMs to be in an availability set though

Comment: Just pointing it out because of the cost perspective. :) I do very much agree standard LBs offer more functionality, the most important one for me being the ability to use availability zones! Which for many organisations is a more important driving factor.